# Smart Phone Sync Issue

Tags: banshee, sync, android

I am trying to sync podcasts from Banshee to my Android phone (HTC Desire). It seems that about 75% of the time when I plug the phone in ubuntu mounts the disk read only, though the mount command says it is read/write.

What is more frustrating is that often it will start, copy over a few podcasts and then the phone's SD card will suddenly become read only and syncing will stop.

What I really want is to have Banshee auto download my podcasts and then copy the new episodes onto my phone when I plug it in.

If using a different podcatcher would work better that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to listen to podcasts on your computer, just download them straight to the smartphone with BeyondPod (installable free from Market). BeyondPod can import OPML files.